# Sum an amount, month to date in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, sum

I have an extense DB but that looks like:

```
|id|amount| office|   date   |
| 1| 50.00|Orlando|2018-11-05|
| 2| 20.00|Orlando|2018-11-09|
| 3| 10.00|Orlando|2018-11-09|
| 4| 80.00|Orlando|2018-11-19|
...
```

Im using this query to get the amount SUM for actual month in a specified office:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS value 
FROM pagos 
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND office = 'Orlando'
```

But im not getting the correct amount (im getting too much), how i know that? because i used this query too and i got the correct amount:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS value 
FROM pagos  
WHERE date between '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-27' 
&& office = 'Orlando'
```

But i need to use the first one with month(curdate()) statement.
The question is, what im doing wrong?

EDIT:

Solution: Exclude other years

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS value FROM pagos WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) && office = 'Orlando'
```

Comment: What value you have and what value you expect?

Comment: You may need to match the year as well to avoid same months in different years.

Comment: You are getting the sum for all months regardless of year so that could be an issue if you only expect 2018

Comment: Add the output of `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) FROM pagos WHERE office='Orlando';` to your question, please. Don't use `value` as alias because it is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mySQL MONTH function only returns the range of 1-12, January to December; if you're getting too much, I suspect that's because your data set includes more than just 2018 dates. Try including a year comparison in your WHERE clause as well as comparing months.